# Gitlab error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: terminal, gitlab

Initially, I had a large folder that was failing to push onto gitlab. I then separated the contents of that large folder into two separate folders.

The first folder successfully pushed but I receive the error below when I try to push the second folder.

Now that I am trying to push the remaining files but receive: 
"error: failed to push some refs to '...' 
"hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally"

Is this occurring because the second folder is missing the contents in the first folder? What do I do to resolve this? I must upload my second folder.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your second folder is not up to date relative to the remote. You can update by using `git fetch` and `git merge`; or `git pull`.